# How to detect mobile devices moves?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am working on mobile site that donate if you are not using your phone.

I was searching on the internet and I found similar project.

http://tap.unicefusa.org/mobile

you need to open it by mobile device.

I am worried how can I detect if the user hold his mobile or he put it down on table or something by jQuery mobile or javascript ?

any Idea how they did that?

Comment: "I am working on mobile site that donate if you are not using your phone" "I am worried how can I detect if the user hold his mobile or he put it down on table or something by jQuery mobile or javascript ?" I don't understand what you are asking?! You want to detect non mobile device or mobile ones or what?

Comment: @A.Wolff sorry about my language .. I need to know if the user hold the mobile by his hand or he just put it down on table or something .. visit the link by your mobile you can understand my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a webpage you can access the [**Gyroscope**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope) using `DeviceMotionEvent`.

simply check if that even exists prior to use it as plenty of mobiles do not allow or do not have such feature.

a good idea on how to start might be an [old post](http://www.peterfriese.de/how-to-use-the-gyroscope-of-your-iphone-in-a-mobile-web-app/) from Peter's blog.

There's also some javascript libraries such as [gyro.js](https://github.com/tomgco/gyro.js) that you might try.